# How can I insert an PHP array into HTML dropdown?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

The function  `get_post_types( '', 'names' )` returns an array containing the names of post types.

```
<?php

$post_types = get_post_types( '', 'names' ); 

foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {

   echo '<p>' . $post_type . '</p>';
}

?>
```

Comment: You need to learn PHP.

Comment: He should start with HTML.

Comment: True that  :) jeez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `HTML` drop down is created using the `<select>` tags with inner `<option>` tags.

You can iterate through the array and print `<option>` tags.

E.g.

```
$post_types = get_post_types('', 'names');

echo "<select>";

foreach($post_types as $post_type) {
    echo "<option value='{$post_type}'>{$post_type}</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`<select>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) HTML element to create a dropdown, and [`<option>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) to create items in the dropdown:

```
<?php

$post_types = get_post_types( '', 'names' );

echo '<select>';

foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
    echo '<option>' . htmlspecialchars($post_type) . '</option>';
}

echo '</select>';

?>
```

**PS:** When inserting text into a HTML document, you should always use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), otherwise you might be subject to [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).